# How to make each fields data to be enclosed with double quotes in CSV file using flutter

Tags: flutter, csv

Is there is anyway I can make it all fields data to be in double quoted? Now fields with comma(,) only coming as double quoted.

For example:

Current output:
1,Sunisha,sunisha@gmail.com,"Abbeville, Louisiana"

Expected output:

"1","Sunisha","sunisha@gmail.com","Abbeville, Louisiana"

pubspec:

```
csv: ^5.0.1
```

Comment: It's hard to tell from skimming over the [`package:csv` documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/csv/latest/index.html), but perhaps try using `ListToCsvConverter(delimitAllFields: true)`?

Comment: @jamesdlin nope not working...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you already have " in the input.. Try removing them before writing it in csv

```
 writeCSV() async {
       List<dynamic> row = [];
       row.add("${someVal.removeAll("\"", "")}");
       rows.add(row);
  }
```

Comment: Hey I have tried this. But that time it is saving in csv like this kind of field value """test""". While opening in text format only we should get double quotes.

Comment: try without dynamic value. For example 
row.add("\"hi\""); probaly you are sending test with double quotes

Comment: Nop in CSV file itself that double quotes coming. I have actually tried this before also.

Comment: https://ibb.co/MBPmLDm

Comment: worked as expected?

Comment: https://ibb.co/BKGqJLj

Comment: Oh in console its displayed like this which means its a string. Ignore the " before and after the real string if you are reading it from console. For example String ab will be displayed as "ab" in console

Comment: No yaa.. see when we generate CSV we don't need double quotes. When we open that CSV file in text we need to get with double quotes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247379/discussion-between-kaushik-chandru-and-sunisha-sindhu).